# How to mock an attribute of an injected object using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, testng, guice

I would like to test the method ***deleteTracks*** and for this I need to mock a Playlist that I retrive after calling `playlistDaoBean.getPlaylistByUUID(uuid)`

```
public class PlaylistBusines {

private PlaylistDao playlistDao;

@Inject
public PlaylistBusinessBean(PlaylistDaoBean playlistDaoBean){
    this.playlistDaoBean = playlistDaoBean;
}

List<PlayListTrack> deleteTracks(String uuid, List<Integer> indexes) throws PlaylistException {


    PlayList playList = playlistDaoBean.getPlaylistByUUID(uuid);
    // TODO

}
```

This is my class test:

```
public class PlaylistBusinessTest {

    @Inject
    PlaylistBusinessBean playlistBusinessBean;


     @Test
    public void testRemoveTracks() throws Exception {

    PlayList playList = new PlayList();
    playList.setId(222)
    playList.setName("fake name");


    PlaylistDaoBean playlistDaoBeanMock = mock(PlaylistDaoBean.class);
    when(playlistDaoBeanMock.getPlaylistByUUID(uuid)).thenReturn(playList);


    playlistBusinessBean.removeTracks(uuid, Arrays.asList(2, 3));


    }
```

Comment: Whats the error? Is this an integration or unit test? How do you inject dao into the bean in the test?

Comment: Hi  Maciej Kowalski , this is a unit test using testng. It is injected by @inject from Guice framework. That part is ok..but I can't get the right result of the attribute of the class injected in the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance under test (PlaylistBusinessBean) is injected by a DI framework. That one, however, is of not using the mock of PlaylistDaoBean created in the test. The mock  is just a local variable, and it is not used anywhere.

Rather than that using an injected instance of PlaylistBusinessBean, create one programatically and pass the PlaylistDaoBean mock to it:

```
public class PlaylistBusinessTest {

     @Test
    public void testRemoveTracks() throws Exception {

    PlayList playList = new PlayList();
    playList.setId(222)
    playList.setName("fake name");


    PlaylistDaoBean playlistDaoBeanMock = mock(PlaylistDaoBean.class);
    when(playlistDaoBeanMock.getPlaylistByUUID(uuid)).thenReturn(playList);

    PlaylistBusinessBean playlistBusinessBean = new PlaylistBusinessBean(playlistDaoBeanMock);

    playlistBusinessBean.removeTracks(uuid, Arrays.asList(2, 3));


    }
```

General notes:

- It's a unit test so I would always recommend to test the code in isolation, independent on DI and any injected code.
- However, if really needed, it is usually also possible a test-specific DI context, that builds injects mocks to beans under tests where required. How to do that depends on the DI used.

Comment: Thanks david, this worked. I didnt know that the @Inject inside the test was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that you haven't provided the mock as an argument to the PlaylistBusines.

It would be worth providing the error, but the mock you're defining the behaviour of is never being used within the class under test.

Comment: Hi Seraph, there was no error. Just that the call playlistDaoBean.getPlaylistByUUID(uuid) didnt bring my playlist done with the ".thenReturn(playList)"